# jQuery Confirm Before Submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```
<form action ="/submit-page/" method='post' class="editable">
    <fieldset>
    <select name="status" id='status'>
        <option value="Submitted">Submitted</option>
        <option value="Canceled">Canceled</option>
              <option value="Application">Application</option>
    </select>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE">

</form>
```

I have a form above: When I click on the drop down value "Canceled" and hit the Save button I want to give alert box with a warning message with a Yes and No button.

If the user cicks on Yes, take him to the submit-page as desired in the form action parameter.
if the user clicks No, stay on the same form page without refreshing the page.
Can this be done in jQuery?

Comment: Do you mean a confirm box like mentioned here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp
Or something like: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-confirm-box

Comment: you should have posted this as the answer :) I was tempted...

Comment: Tutorial here: [Modal Confirmation Dialog on Form Submit](http://www.jensbits.com/2009/08/10/modal-confirmation-dialog-on-form-submit-javascript-jquery-ui-and-thickbox-varieties/). It includes a plain js example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm... theres is a problem with the other answers on here: they don't work against your HTML.

There's a bug in jQuery (I assume it's a bug), where if an element on your form has  a`name` of `submit`, then triggering the `submit` event of the form will not work.

You will need to remove the `name` attribute from your `input type="submit"` button or simply give it a name other than "submit".

**HTML**

```
<form action ="/submit-page/" method='post' class="editable">
  <fieldset>
    <select name="status" id='status'>
      <option value="Submitted">Submitted</option>
      <option value="Canceled">Canceled</option>
      <option value="Application">Application</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="SAVE" name="submit-button"/>
  </fieldset>
</form>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#status').on('change', function() {

    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val();

    if (val === 'Canceled' && confirm("are you sure?")) {
        $this.closest('form').submit();
    }
});​
```

**PHP**

```
$submitted = !empty($_POST['submit-button']);

if($submitted)
{
    // Submit button was pressed.
}
else
{
    // Form was submitted via alternate trigger.
}
```

**Example**

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/xixonia/KW5jp/

Not Working: http://jsfiddle.net/xixonia/KW5jp/1/

***Edit***

You have since updated your question, and this answer is no longer a valid solution for what you are looking for. Instead, look at [Chris Platt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436254/696056).

***Edit Again***

This is a modified version of [Chris Platt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436254/696056). It simply waits until the DOM is ready (elements are loaded) before it executes the logic contained within the first `$(...)`.

```
$(function() { // this first jQuery object ensures that...

    /// ... the code inside executes *after* the DOM is ready.

    $('form.editable').submit(function(){
        if ($('#status').val()=='Canceled') {
            if (!confirm('Warning message here. Continue?')) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: @Christopher..if I remove the name , how will check at the server side that the submit button was pressed: foe example if i want to check
if(!empty($_POST['submit']))

Comment: You can simply *change* the name. It does not need to be removed entirely. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I tried Chris Platt's answer..but it doesnt work on this site :
http://srikanthrajan.com/test/
i tried including different jquery libraries but it doesn't work

Comment: @ CHRIS do u think it's the library?

Comment: Ahh... You will need to either place your javascript *after* the form, or execute it after the document is ready. I will update my answer to include this.

Comment: thanks Chris..i tried ur code both ways..but it still doesn't provide the warning message

Comment: Your script wont execute because you have a misspelling in your last script type. You've told the browser that the script type is `text/javscript`, instead of `text/javascript`. Therefore, because the browser doesn't know what that is, the browser doesn't treat it as a script at all. Fix the typo, and everything will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form.editable').submit(function(){
    if ($('#status').val()=='Canceled') {
        if (!confirm('Warning message here. Continue?')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not what the user asked for.

Comment: It's one interpretation of what the user asked for. His question title says "after submitting a form".

Comment: thanks everyone..Chris Pratts solution seems ideal for my current situation.. but it does not work ..when i click on the Save button it does not generate the Warning message if the status is 'Canceled'..

Comment: @newbie So, you want the confirmation dialog to appear only after the user has clicked submit, and only if the 'Canceled' option is selected? If so, Chris's solution does indeed work: http://jsfiddle.net/xixonia/euW7A/

Answer (score 0):

yes, it can be done:

```
$('#status').change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
   if( val == 'Submitted' ) {
     $('.editable').submit();
     return false;
   } else if (val == 'Canceled')
   {
      var answer = confirm('are you sure');
      return false;
   } else {
    ... 
   }
});
```

This, as opposed to Chris Pratts solution will do it, as soon as you change the selected value in the dropdown box. His will do it, once you click the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct method to intercept the form submission in jQuery is like this:

```
$("form.editable").submit(function(){
    if(confirm("Really submit the form?")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; //form will not be sumitted and page will not reload
    }
});
```

See http://jqapi.com/#p=submit for more detail.