# confirm delete with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

How can we confirm the deletion of an array element result of an ajax call?

I have an array :

```
$.ajax({  
           url: "recursive.php",
           method:"POST",
           dataType: "json",       
           success: function(data)  
               {
                  $('#treeview').treeview({
                      data: data
                  });
               }   
      });
```

In my `recursive.php` I have this code:

```
$arr = array(
        'text' => '<img src="img/pdf.png"><a href="delete.php?doc='.$sub_data["code"].' "target="_blank">'.$sub_data["n_doc"].'</a>
       '
       );
```

In this `<a href`, I need to confirm before deleting.
in delete.php i have:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, ' DELETE FROM saisie WHERE code = "'.$doc.'" ') or die (mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Confirm Before Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436199/jquery-confirm-before-submit)

Comment: no it's not the same question

Comment: answer is to use the technique in the dupe

Comment: @hananeazee your AJAX does not POST any data to the PHP. Why not just use `$.getJSON()`. Also what is not working? Any console errors? What do you see in Network tab of developer tools?

Comment: You can add an event handler on the parent. Give your `<a>` tag a class name or an identifier so you can find it.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you wanting to confirm that an action took place? or are you wanting to pop up a dialog that the user wants to click to confirm that they want an action to took place? what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I did not understand your solution, an example please .  Kevin B

Comment: I did not provide a solution? I asked for you to improve your question.

Comment: when I click on the link in the table it deletes the file without confirmation, what I want is ask the client to confirm before deleting

Comment: Then your question is a duplicate of the question linked in the first comment.

Comment: I tried several solutions but nothing works like: onclick="return(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?'));"

Comment: Try to make a function that return "return (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?'));" and return the function in the <a> tag.

Comment: I already tried, but it did not work  Richard Socker

Answer (score 0):

Make another ajax call in the  success function:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $.ajax({  
           url: "recursive.php",
           method:"POST",
           dataType: "json",       
           success: function(data)  
               { 
                   $(document).on('click', '.btn_supp', function(){
                       if(confirm("do you want to delete this file?")){
                         $.ajax({  
                          url: "delete.php",
                          method:"POST",
                           dataType: "json",       
                         success: function(data)  
                         {
                         alert("deleted");
                         });
                        }   
                        });
                       }
                   });   
                  $('#treeview').treeview({
                      data: data,
                      selectedBackColor: 'rgb(211,211,211)',
                      selectedColor: '#4A4A49',
                      enableLinks:true,
                      collapsedall: true
                  });
               }   
      });`
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method of accomplishing displaying a confirmation when AJAX adds to the DOM,  would be to bind a delegated event listener in your view's DOMReady function.

Since jQuery binds event handlers during the `DOMReady` state, it will not bind additional elements in the `ajax.success` function, unless the response includes javascript and the `dataType` is 'script' or you parse the `data` variable from the success function and an event is manually added.

This assumes an element with an `id="treeview"`, already exists.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', 'a[href^="delete.php"]', function(e) {
        return window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?');
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "recursive.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType: "json",       
        success: function(data) {
            $('#treeview').treeview({
                data: data,
                selectedBackColor: 'rgb(211,211,211)',
                selectedColor: '#4A4A49',
                enableLinks:true,
                collapsedall: true
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="treeview"></div>
```

This works by telling jQuery to monitor all of the clicks inside of the `#treeview` element, for a triggering element of `<a href="delete.php">`. Specifically `href^="delete.php"` means an `<a>` element, with an `href` that begins with `delete.php`. If one is found, the callback function is executed and the confirmation dialog is displayed.

---

If you add a `class` attribute to your `recursive.php` anchor element, you can replace `a[href^="delete.php"]` with `a.classname`.

### Example https://jsfiddle.net/ub1hw9tn/

```
$arr = array(
    'text' => '<img src="img/pdf.png"><a class="delete" href="delete.php?doc='.$sub_data["code"].'" target="_blank">'.$sub_data["n_doc"].'</a>'
);
```

Then in your javascript

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.delete', function(e) {
    if (!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?')) {
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: your answer seems to me very logical but it did not work it removes without displaying the confirmation

Comment: I tried this code it displays the confirmation msg but does not delete if we click on ok or cancel it does not do anything:$(document).on('click ', 'a.delete', function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              return window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this file?');
         }); @Fyrye

Comment: @hananeazee remove the `e.preventDefault()` to allow the event to bubble up through the dom after `confirm` is called. I was using it to catch the click event and demonstrate that it was being prevented. in general you would use `e.prevenDefault();` after the window.confirm, rather than returning false. I updated the answer.